# Error:Failed to resolve: support-annotations

Tags: android, gradle

Eu fui remover bibliotecas externas do meu projeto pois estava a receber erros de versões misturadas da biblioteca appCompat, tentei eliminar tudo relacionado com a versão 25.2.0 porque preciso usar a 22.2.1 `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'`. O erro acontece quando tento o sync do Gradle, veja a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso readicioanar o que me é pedido.

**UPDATE:**

recebo este erro se tentar fazer build:

> Error:Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
>
> > Could not find support-annotations.jar (com.android.support:support-annotations:25.2.0).
> >       Searched in the following locations:
> >           file:/G:/Static/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.2.0/support-annotations-25.2.0.jar

Comment: Não coloque imagem de erro na pergunta, mas sim o texto do erro, ex: Errot: Failed to resolve: support-annotations. Facilita a leitura e ajudar na busca pela mensagem de erro pelos mecanismos de indexação, exemplo google.

Comment: eu coloquei o nome por escrito, só queria evitar respostas erradas. Eu já vi erros deste tipo, mas no erro estava a versão que estava em falta, na imagem fica claro que eu coloquei a informação toda, e que não tem nada sobre a versão

Answer (score 0):

Tem de adicionar no bloco *dependencies* do build.gradle a seguinte dependência:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.1'
```

Comment: O erro continua igual, se colocar na ultima versão (27.0.2) esse erro desaparece, mas depois fico sem classes no código. Ex: `import android.support.v4.app` dá erro se colocar a ultima versão.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o build.gradle